# Lua: C++ Type Instances and Garbage Collector

Tags: c++, lua

I have a problem with gargabe collection in Lua. The problem is:

1. I have an instance of my type (defined in C++).
2. This instance has an int-based reference to Lua table.
3. In this table I have an instance of my other type (defined in C++).
4. Garbage collector tries to delete the second instance.

The first type instances can't be collected by garbage collector, so they always exists. The table is in a one of these instances, so it always exists too. Why garbage collector thinks it's contents should not exist?

I tried to create a table with the first instances, and it doesn't help. What shall I do to make garbage collector work properly?

Comment: `The table is in a one of these instances, so it always exists too` - What does this mean?  If a C++ object contains a Lua table, then how Lua GC can see this reference?

Comment: `What shall I do to make garbage collector work properly?` - You should anchor your Lua table.

Comment: Probably, you have a point. The API provides method LUA->ReferenceCreate, which returns an int, which is the reference to the value in the top of the stack, which can be get with LUA->ReferencePush. I thought, these tables will be never collected, until LUA->ReferenceFree, but maybe they will. Neverthelless, garbage collector doesn't remove these tables. It only removes the values, which are UserData from them. Maybe, it'll delete them after removing all the values.

Comment: If the collector is deleting individual entries from a table but not the table itself, it sounds like you have a weak table[1]; this is a table that holds references to objects but does not prevent them from being collected. It is used to allow fast object lookup without being "a reference" to the object.

`LUA->ReferenceCreate` is probably luaL_ref[2] which can be used to create references in any table; try creating them in a non-weak table or the Lua Registry.

[1] https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5.4
[2] https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_ref

Comment: I think, you are right about it. Unfortunately, it means, I can't store tables in a C++ object by reference. (